# How to organize your ideas, how to keep reasonable when writing

Tags: creative-writing, writers-block

I tried to write about specific subject but i had a problem which is: I always lose concentration and forget some important things to write. Sometimes, a secondary idea comes to my mind and made me lose concentration and focus on the principal one. This is my problem with writing.

Comment: Sounds like you've failed to plan it out. You've got a great idea, rushed off to write it but it's not fully formed. Doesn't matter if it's a 300 word essay or a novel, you still need to plan it out to avoid the exact situation you've found yourself in. Just remember the 5 P's - Proper Planning Prevents Poor Performance

Comment: All the answers given to you are great. Before you start writing, think hard about what you want to say. Imagine it in your head. Grab pen and paper and jot down ideas. First write the principal one. Keep it at the top of the page. When you lose focus, refer to it. Then jot down ideas as they come. When the well of ideas drains, look at the paper. See what you wrote and organize them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before I start writing any complicated document, I open a second Word document open and put it in the Outline view.  This view (mode) allows me to write one line statements and to easily hang them in a hierarchy.  I then summarize a plan for the document such as...

[image: Sample Outline]

Tab and shift-Tab move individual lines left and right and the enter key can create new lines anywhere within the hierarchy.  Cut and paste function as you would expect.  It is a very easy tool to use and you could then type your document right into the outline.  I usually just use it as a separate guide while I write in another instance of Word.

If new ideas distract me while I am writing, I add them to the outline before adding them to my actual document.  Then, when I am done, I can compare the finished document to the original outline, to make sure that I haven't omitted anything.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this problem a while ago. My remedy is merrily to open a document and basically brain dump your ideas into it, while adding to it as you go.

As for the organization of this "brain dump," I label the events in chronological order, I have this system.

> Draft
>   Ch. 16
>   Greyson and Haku reunite 
>   Liam meets Haku, gets along well with
>   Greyson gets angry with Sumiko
>   Scolds her because she made all of Dweebus Babus’s hybrids
>   Greyson tells story of Search
>   Haku tells story of Revelation.
>
> Ch. 15
>   History of elves
>
> Ch. 14
>   Haku returns home
>   Sumiko surprises Haku with another Hybrid (bird/mouse)
>   Tells story of experience
>   Flash back of fight, remembers what he can do
>   Experiment with abilities
>   Accidentally hurts May
>   Vows not to use power again
>
> Ch. 13
>   Gets home finds Haku isn’t there
>   Goes looking for Haku
>
> Ch. 12
>   Elves land on earth
>   Encounters wolves
>   Find ore and mines it
>   Takes specimens back in ship to analyse
>
> Ch. 10
>   Tim wakes up
>   Tells Haku story about past
>   Scene flip to Greyson and Liam in hotel close to home
>   Liam experiences proper civilization for the first time
>   Trip to house
>   Flat tire and bandits
>   Arrival to neighborhood.
>
> Ch. 17
>   Talks about Ryu’s creation
>   Re-introduce topic of Ryu’s betrayal to Sumiko
>   Explain what happened
>   Go into depth on thoughts and feelings

and so on. But from these basic ideas, I can come up with a whole story about it. I hope this helps.

Comment: I do exactly this. Sometimes at the ends of chapters in the book I also make notes. Word processors (and notebooks) are awesome. Oh, I also keep a notebook.

Comment: Notebooks help TREMENDOUSLY